# Includes no funcionan correctamente, tengo que meter la conexion pasando el codigo completo a otro archivo php para que funcione

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, azure

El archivo db_connect.php no funciona a traves de includes ni requires, solo pasando el codigo completo de la conexion a los queries, necesito saber por que no funciona con includes la conexion a la base de datos

Despues el error que me arroja en que la variable que llama a la db no esta definida asi:

> Warning: Undefined variable $conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\Inventario-main\load_data_header.php on line 6

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Inventario-main\load_data_header.php:6 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Inventario-main\dashboard.php(63): include() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Inventario-main\index.php(47): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Inventario-main\load_data_header.php on line 6

**db_connect.php**

```php
        <?php 
        $host = 'inventario-db.mysql.database.azure.com';
        $username = 'admin';
        $password = 'pass';
        $db_name = 'inventario';

        //Initializes MySQLi
        $conn = mysqli_init(); 

        mysqli_ssl_set($conn, NULL, NULL , NULL, NULL, NULL);

        //Establish the connection
        mysqli_real_connect($conn, 'inventario-db.mysql.database.azure.com', 'admin', 'pass', 'inventario', 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);

        //If connection failed, show the error
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            die('Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        ?>
```

**load_data_header.php** (no funciona el include de db_connect.php asi)

```php
    <?php include 'db_connect.php' ?>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
        <?php
        $qry = $conn->query("SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) as pending FROM tickets t where not status=2 group by id,subject,description,status,department_id,employee_id,staff_id,admin_id,date_created");
        while($row= $qry->fetch_assoc()):?>
          <div class="small-box bg-warning elevation-1">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3><?php echo $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tickets")->num_rows; ?></h3>
              <p>Tickets</p>
              <?php if ($row['pending'] <= 0): ?> 
                <b style="display:none;"><?php echo $row ['pending'] ?></b><b>Everything is done!</b>
              <?php elseif ($row['pending'] >= 1): ?> 
                <b><?php echo $row['pending']?></b> tickets are pending!
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

**load_data_header.php** (funciona al pasar el codigo php de db_connect.php asi)

```php
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
        <?php
        $host = 'inventario-db.mysql.database.azure.com';
        $username = 'admin';
        $password = 'pass';
        $db_name = 'inventario';
        
        //Initializes MySQLi
        $conn = mysqli_init(); 
        
        mysqli_ssl_set($conn,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, NULL);
        
        //Establish the connection
        mysqli_real_connect($conn, 'inventario.db.mysql.database.azure.com', 'admin', 'pass', 'inventario', 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
        
        //If connection failed, show the error
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            die('Failed to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        $qry = $conn->query("SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) as pending FROM tickets t where not status=2 group by id,subject,description,status,department_id,employee_id,staff_id,admin_id,date_created");
        while($row= $qry->fetch_assoc()):?>
          <div class="small-box bg-warning elevation-1">
            <div class="inner">
              <h3><?php echo $conn->query("SELECT * FROM tickets")->num_rows; ?></h3>
              <p>Tickets</p>
              <?php if ($row['pending'] <= 0): ?> 
                <b style="display:none;"><?php echo $row ['pending'] ?></b><b>Everything is done!</b>
              <?php elseif ($row['pending'] >= 1): ?> 
                <b><?php echo $row['pending']?></b> tickets are pending!
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Ambos archivos php están en la misma carpeta??

Comment: @SBK22 esta en un repos de github, pero si estan en la misma carpeta, estoy intentando de correrlo con localhost

Comment: @SBK22 pero sigue sin funcionar